# Reversible length reducing of string to decrease memory

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I have **~100 millions** of unique strings that are **30 characters long**.

I would like to reduce their size in memory.

As there are 100 millions distinct values of them, in theory I could compress the information in **5 characters** because 62^5 gives 900M possibilities.

Any smart way to achieve that ?

What I was thinking of :

- sort them in alphabetical order
- transform this rank in base(62)

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: I don't like to reinvent the wheel. If there is a memory-reducing concept existing in the wild, I would like to know it. I was thinking I should not be the only one on Earth with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `StringIndexer` method in PySpark which was exactly what I needed.

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#stringindexer